# Execute SQL query based on results of a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL knowledge is somewhat limited. I have 2 Select statements that returns separate sets of results. Since the tables being queried are different sets of tables for each Select statement I would like to know if it is possible to write it such that it picks which query to execute based on the result returned from a Select Statement on a completely different table, for example:

```
Select C.ManBtchNum from Table C
   If OITM.ManBtchNum = 'Y' then
       Select * from Table A
   else
       Select * from Table B
```

Apologies for using psuedocode but its the shortest way I can explain this.

I'm not sure if a Case expression can be used here. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

I have tried both a Case as well as a Union but I'm not getting the results needed. Granted I might be doing something wrong considering my limited knowledge

Comment: first time i see "select table", is it a typo or a rdms I didn't know?

Comment: This is probably doable using an INNER JOIN to both tables and a COALESCE or a CASE. Please provide some sample data from these three tables and desired results from that sample data and we can help further.

Comment: Create procedure, declare variable, fill variable from first query (single value!), use `if @variable = xxx ... else ...` (using correct syntax). Better avoid `select *` - rather use specified fields list.

Comment: Is there a way to join the possible result sets and keep the values similar?
Or does result set 1 have the potential to return numeric and the other result return a different data type (char, date, etc) so that queries could get errors based on the results?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm using sql-server.

Comment: @Arvo - I think a stored proc will probably best for this instance. I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an example,

```
select t1.Val, t2.Val, t3.Val,               
case                                                  
when(t1.Val = Something)Then (T2.Val)Else(t3.Val)
END 
from tablex t1 
inner join tabley t2 on t1.commonfield = t2.commonfield
inner join tablez t3 ON t1.commonfield = t3.commonfield
```